# How to create type for an object and display the name of that object

Tags: typescript

I am using react-data-table-component library to display some data from the backend

The data received is like this:

```
[
{
  id:1,
  nickname:"nickname"
  Users:[{
    name:"username"
  }]
}
]
```

The datatable requires 2 parameters as props, columns, and data.

the type for this i have done like this:

```
type DataRow = {
  id: number;
  nickname:string,
  Users:string
};
```

and column prop:

```
const columns: TableColumn<DataRow>[] = [
  {
    name: "ID",
    selector: (row) => row.id,
  }, 
   {
    name: "nickname",
    selector: (row) => row.nickname,
  },  
  {
    name: "name of the user",
    selector: (row) => row.Users.name, // ERROR: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'
  },
];
```

Comment: Does the question depend on people knowing react-data-table-component?  If so, then please tag it as such.  If not, then please consider providing a [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.

Comment: No there is no need for knowledge of react-data-table, It is just a typescript error I think. @jcalz

Comment: Then please [edit] the example code text to be reproducible. [A standalone IDE doesn't like most of that code](https://tsplay.dev/wXj8Jm), for reasons you are not asking about.  (Unless you are asking about indeclared/undefined types/values and syntactically invalid data, but I don't think you are).

Comment: It seems the question is specific to `react-data-table-component`. I think `TableColumn` expects *input* data type (in your case it's `{ id: number; nickname: string; Users: { username: string }[] }`), not output data type (which is what you currently have as `DataRow`, and it matches data shape produced by running selectors). So, the fix is to change `DataRow` definition to match input data. Disclaimer: not an React expert, just reading some code and docs.